# Microsoft Teams Adaptive Cards Aren't Showing Notifications on iOS

Tags: microsoft-teams

We've been using Botbuilder.js version 4 to send adaptive cards into Teams for our bot. This seems to work for Web, Desktop and even Android Teams. When we do the same thing for iOS it is not working. Has anyone dealt with this before?

```
 var response = MessageFactory.Text(string.Empty);
 response.Attachments.Add(cardAttachment);
 response.Summary = "showing custom greeeting from the Bot - rather than a card";
 await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
```

[Android Push Notification - has summary text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN6Vp.png) 
[iOS Push Notification - missing summary text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5s9r.png)

This is the same Summary text for the same adaptive card. Appreciate any ideas!!

Comment: We are able to repro this issue and we have raised a bug for it.

Comment: Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT that's awesome!! Thank you. Can you link me to the bug (if its public like github?) thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mark Alayev - The bug is internally raised. Its not publically accessible.

Comment: Hi @Nivedipa-MSFT, can you update us about the issue?

Comment: @NDM-MobileDEV - Engineering team is currently working on the fix. We will update you.

Comment: This bug has been fixed now. Could you please test it and confirm once?

Comment: This bug has been fixed now. We have tested this on IOS Teams version 5.12.0 and IOS version 16.5.1

Could you please test it and confirm once?